# Bitcoin Core coin control via RPC (CLI)

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, coin-control

Bitcoin Core introduced nice Coin Control feature accessible via the GUI client. To my surprise though, I don't see any obvious way how to make use of Coin Control via RPC/bitcoin-cli.

How can I pick a particular unspent output when creating a transaction via RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but the process is broken up into multiple RPCs.

First you use the `listunspent` RPC to find outputs to spend.

Then you use `createrawtransaction` with the inputs you want, and the outputs (destinations) you want.

If you didn't select all inputs and outputs already (including change, if necessary - any difference between inputs and outputs goes to fees), you can use `fundrawtransaction` to add more inputs using the normal coin selection algorithm, or to add change.

Then you use `signrawtransaction` to sign your inputs.

When all is ready, you can broadcast your transaction using `sendrawtransaction`.

Comment: Thanks, this really seems to be the only way as of now. Perhaps we'll get a more higher level API someday.